# Creating a dark mode for Google Docs using CSS

Tags: css, google-docs

I've been trying to make myself a simple night mode for google docs using CSS (through a custom CSS chrome extension), but I'm having a lot of trouble. Mind you I only have basic Highschool CSS knowledge, and no more.

I am aware there are extensions for this sort of thing, but those extensions always make EVERYTHING dark, and I really don't want everything dark, just the sides/background (which I've already managed to find), the "explore" button on the bottom right (with visible text), and the outline button on the top left (With a visible icon)

This is what I've managed to find so far (Just for the sides / background):

```
.kix-appview-editor-container,.gb_Va {
    background: #131719;
    color: white;
}

.docs-gm-dialogs .docs-findinput-container, .docs-gm-dialogs .docs-gotoinput-container, .docs-copydocdialog-destination-button, .docs-material.docs-navigation-tab-button.goog-inline-block {
    border: 0;
}
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how to darken the 2 buttons (bonus if someone can also darken the little bubble button that pops up to the right when you highlight text, but I'll take what I can get).

Any help (or improvements to what I already have) would be hugely appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Some of this might be browser dependent, as Google loves to do. But I don't see a button pop up when I highlight text. The Outline button styes for me with: 
`<div class="navigation-widget docs-material navigation-widget-navigation-tab-button navigation-widget-hoverable" role="group" tabindex="0" aria-label="Document Outline" style="width: 264px; left: 0px; opacity: 1;">`
And the icon inside it: 
`<div class="docs-icon-img docs-icon-list-24 docs-icon-img-container">`

Comment: I'm sorry but isn't that HTML? Sadly I'm limited to only using CSS, sorry about that.

Comment: Yes but it shows the classes you can try styling in CSS, something like: 
`.navigation-widget.docs-material.navigation-widget-navigation-tab-button.navigation-widget-hoverable { background: #999}`(applies to div with all those classes). Or try one or two.

Comment: I'm sorry but pasting that in the CSS extension didn't do anything. Thanks for taking the time to try though.